# Apportable supports Navigation using Segues

Tags: ios, apportable

I was just exploring Apportable's new SDKs for converting iOS app to Android App.

Was facing problem when try to move to another View Controller using Segues(modal).
Any idea that they support it or not.

If so any example for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

our current UIKit doesn't have very good support for segues or modals, we'll have more to talk about in coming months. thanks for trying out apportable!

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the response. Also keep updating us on the same.